# preventDefault won't work on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I'm trying to prevent A HREF from actually opening the link, but to execute a script. I got the script part working, but it seems Firefox would just ignore this:

```
$("#permalink a").click(function(id){
  $("#newPost").fadeToggle;
  event.preventDefault();
  var id = this.getAttribute('href');
  $("#newPostContent").load(id);
  $("#newPost").show("fast");
});
```

Can anyone suggest a cross-browser script for preventing defaults?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The standard solution to this is to `return false` from the `click()` handler. `return false` is the equivalent of calling `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()` on the event. `preventDefault()` is sufficient for this task too so either it or `return false` will work.

Your problem seems to be syntax errors and misnamed parameters. I see:

- `fadeToggle` has no parentheses;
- the function parameter is called `id` yet you call `event.preventDefault()`; and
- You're fading the post and then immediately showing it? That'll queue two animations but doesn't make a lot of sense. You probably want to chain together those two things and the `load()` in a rational manner.

So this should work:

```
$("#permalink a").click(function(event) {
  $("#newPost").fadeToggle();
  var id = this.getAttribute('href');
  $("#newPostContent").load(id);
  $("#newPost").show("fast");
  return false;
});
```

You can freely replace `return false` with `event.preventDefault()` in this instance but the propagating `click()` event might or might cause other issues depending on what other event handlers you have.

Comment: "Hey what's going on on this side?"

Comment: That's not the problem here. The problem is .click(function(id){ should be .click(function(event){.

Comment: "But whatever the case, preventing link navigation is best done by return false from the click event handler." - actually, it's not - that screws up if you require events to propagate properly.  It's a *lazier* way to do it, requiring less code, but preventDefault does precisely what is required (no default action) and nothing more.

Comment: Because of what karim79 and ijw have said. Thanks karim79!! I had .click(function(){event.preventDefault();}); which worked perfect in chrome but failed in firefox. Changing this to .click(function(event){event.preventDefault();}); worked perfect in both.

Anyone coming here and blindly taking this advice should read this: http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/

Answer (score 21):

This always works:
Firefox needs the "event handler", Chrome doesn't. So this works on all browsers:

```
$('#id_obj').click(function(event) {   
     event.preventDefault(event);  
}
```

Comment: event.preventDefault(event) should be event.preventDefault() - neither the jquery reference or the dom reference suggest that the preventDefault method accepts parameters.  The former is probably irrelevant because it is the dom event that is fired in the end.

Comment: For me, it was that the `event` was not getting passed into the click function, so just changing it from `$('id_obj').click(function(){` to `$('#id_obj').click(function(event){` did the trick. Passing `event` into the `preventDefault` method didn't change anything.

Comment: This works! This saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 14):

```
            $("#permalink a").click(function(id){
```

should be

```
            $("#permalink a").click(function(event){
```

Then

```
var id=event.target;
```

will give you the object you're working on, and event.preventDefault() will stop the default action.

Typically I return false; myself, but this both prevents the default action *and* stops propagation of the event, which might have effects you didn't expect with other event handlers.

Comment: ... actually, I note that you pass 'id' in but it's overridden by your attribute-fetch.  Better still, the 'id' variable is not an id when passed in (it's an event obj though I assumed you thought it was the DOM object) nor when you get the attr (then, it's a URI).  That plus the missing brackets on your fadeToggle call says to me that you need to read the code you've written a bit more carefully before you start pointing fingers at the jQuery library.

Answer (score -1):

You should just be able to `return false;`

Comment: "Back you go answer, to waits for for a questioner with less discerning tastes.'