# event.preventDefault not working in mozilla

Tags: javascript

its wrking in ie but not in mozilla wats the alternate

```
  function preventBackspace(e) {

          var evt = e || window.event;
         // alert(evt);
          if (evt) {
              var keyCode = evt.charCode || evt.keyCode;
             // alert(keyCode);
              if (keyCode === 8) {
                if (evt.preventDefault) {
            evt.preventDefault();
                 } else {
                      evt.returnValue = false;
                 }
              }
          }
      }
```

infact evt.returnvalue=false is not wrking in mozilla

Comment: It should work equally well in most modern browsers. Care to show us some of your code ?

Comment: this is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367195/preventdefault-wont-work-on-firefox

Comment: @oezi, in that question, the problem was misnamed paramaeters and syntax errors.  There's no reason to think it's the same issue here.

Comment: @vakas: Can you post some code? I don't really see how a DOM2 event method is actually working on  IE!

Comment: i have editted my question, infact evt.returnvalue is not working

Comment: @vakas: I would like to know: What event are you binding?, To what kind of element? and How do you bind it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a simple test ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KBFjV/)), and your function *does* work in Firefox.  As expected, it never executes the non-standard returnValue part.