# AJAX in Django with jQuery quite confusing

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I'm a jQuery noob here, please help! Much much appreciated!

my urls.py:
`url('^xhr_test/$','posts.views.xhr_test'),`

my views.py:

```
def xhr_test(request):
if request.is_ajax():
    message = "Hello AJAX"
else:
    message = "Hello"
return HttpResponse(message)
```

So, very simple. This setup works if one of two versions of my HTML page.

HTML version 1 is a success:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.get("xhr_test", function(data) {
           alert(data);
       });
});
</script>
```

That's that. The AJAX request is made whenever the page is done loading. So that much works, and I get a nice alert box that says "Hello AJAX"

Now HTML version 2 does not work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("a").click(function() {
       alert("hi");
       $.get("xhr_test", function(data) {
           alert(data);
       });
   });
});
<a href="">Click here</a>
```

So when I click "Click here" I get an alert with "hi" in it, and then nothing. Nothing seems to be sent nor received, because I don't see anything in Firebug. I also tried changing the request URL from "xhr_test" to "myApp/xhr_test" and "/myApp/xhr_test" to no avail.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much!

---

---

---

---

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an `event.preventDefault();` to your code; e.g.:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("a").click(function() {
       event.preventDefault();
       alert("hi");
       $.get("xhr_test", function(data) {
           alert(data);
       });
   });
});
<a href="">Click here</a>
```

Comment: THAT WORKED! Thank you so much! Could you explain that? I suppose what it does is it prevents the element from doing what it's originally supposed to do, that is going to the url in href?

Comment: @Rabbid, that is exactly what is happening. Another option you will see used is having the click function return false

Comment: Note that I just found out preventDefault() does not work in Firefox. Looks like the standard solution is to use `return false;` after all.

Comment: @rabbid I'm assuming you've seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367195/preventdefault-wont-work-on-firefox