# Jquery Ajax response doesn't work on Firefox

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, firefox

This is the response in php. I can confirm the datas are ok.

```
 $ajax_response = array(
    'product_code' => $ajax_products,
    'filter' => $ajax_filter
);

echo json_encode($ajax_response);
exit();
```

Here is the code in javascript :

```
$('#pr_category_filter').submit(function (event) {

    $.ajax({
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {

            if (data.product_code != null) {
                $('#pagination_contents').replaceWith(data.product_code);
            }

            if (data.filter != null) {
                $('#category_filter').replaceWith(data.filter);
            }
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    event.preventDefault(event);

});
```

This code works well on Chrome and Opera. However, this code doesn't work on Firefox because the php "echo" is displayed on Firefox instead of ajax response. I also tried to put a console.debug('invoked') in the javascript. No result is displayed in Firefox in contrary of Chrome. Do you know the reason ?

The response is the same into browsers tools development.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "php 'echo' is displayed on Firefox instead of ajax response"??

Comment: In normal case, ajax response is replaced into tags with id pagination_contents and #category_filter. On Firefox, the ajax response is displayed on the screen like a new http request / response. In other words, there is a new page with ajax response.

Comment: I don't know, but I find it strange your `error:` function is returning a value. The `error:` and `success:` are callback functions. Where would this value be going to?

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Answer (score 1):

The function [.preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) does not accept any arguments.

Probably Firefox therefore does not accept this and simply submits the form. Chrome however does not really care and does accept it.

So change

```
event.preventDefault(event);
```

Into

```
event.preventDefault();
```

That should do the trick

Comment: No, it doesn't work. event.preventDefault() was my first version, but I changed after reading a post on this website.

Comment: Here is the link which explains the difference between event.preventDefault(event); and event.preventDefault(); : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367195/preventdefault-wont-work-on-firefox

Comment: According to jQuery documentation, the function does not accept any arguments. https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: Does the javascript run at all?

Comment: Yes, it does. It's only this function which does't work on Firefox.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, did you check the console for any errors?

Comment: Don't worry for late reply. I checked the console and no error was found.

Comment: @cscart_swissboy that link doesn't explain that, it explains the difference between `$('#foo').click(function(event){event.preventDefault()}` and `$('#foo').click(function(){event.preventDefault()}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `header()` function in PHP to specify the content-type of the response you're returning to the AJAX call. Try the following (place it before you echo the response):

```
header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

Comment: No, it's doesn't work. Your code is the same thing as  dataType: 'json', in the javascript.